# include into if with nunjucks in nodejs

Tags: node.js, templates, express, render, nunjucks

I working on user's system with nodejs.
I used express and nunjucks.
I trying to render a template when the user logged to the site and anoter template when the user logoff.

```
{% if isLoging %}
        {% include "toolbar_guest.html" %}
{% else %}
        {% include "toolbar_guest.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

but its not working...
if I try this:

```
{% if isLoging %}
        connected
{% else %}
    not connected!
{% endif %}
```

its work..

Comment: `{% include 'toolbar_user.html' if isLogging else 'toolbar_guest.html' %}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{% include 'toolbar_user.html' if isLogging else 'toolbar_guest.html' %}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.